# Discord.py wait_for message... How to take the message content and the person who wrote the message?

Tags: python, async-await, discord, discord.py, bots

I'm searching to write a shutdown-room command, that mute all the users in a specific room.
So, I have to get the user that wrote the message and the message content.

For now I have this, but in this case every message is monitored:

```
def shut_check(msg):
   return msg.content

@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def shut_room(ctx):

   await ctx.send("Please send me the id of the room that you want to shut down.")

   content = await client.wait_for("message", check=check)
```

Now, I have the **content** of the message sent, but how can I verify **if the author** of the message **is the ctx.author?**

I have **another request**, can you explain to me what's the purpose of the `pass_context=True` in:

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple logic, define the `check` function inside the command. Also your current check doesn't make any sense at all, it will always return a true-like value

```py
@client.command()
async def shut_room(ctx):
    def check(msg):
        return msg.author == ctx.author

    await ctx.send("Please send me the id of the room that you want to shut down.")

    message = await client.wait_for("message", check=check)
    content = message.content
```

Also when waiting for a message it doesn't return the content itself, but a `discord.Message` instance, I think you got confused with the check function.

Explaining the `check` parameter: the bot will wait for the desired event until the `check` function returns a truthy value.

EDIT:

Defining the check func outside the command

```py
def check(ctx):
    def inner(msg): # This is the actual check function, the one that holds the logic
        return msg.author == ctx.author
    return inner

# inside the command
message = await client.wait_for("message", check=check(ctx)) # Note that I'm calling it
```

I've wrapped the check function with another function so I can pass the `Context` argument.

Comment: Yes, I got confused with the check function, anyway thank you bro.

Comment: What if I don't want put the function definition into the command?
I mean, is it possible to get the ctx.author out of the command?

Comment: Not exactly, but yes - it's possible to define the check func outside the command

Comment: How can I do this, in a few words?  This isn't necessary but it would be much comfortable.

Comment: I edited the answer a while ago, check it out